# window.speechSynthesis on mobile devices while asleep

Tags: javascript, android, ios, text-to-speech

I'm trying to build a start-to-run web-app. As such my users need the app to run in the background to keep track of time, geolocation and to make announcements of progress using `window.speechSynthesis.speak`.

I need it to work when the phone is asleep, which I realise is often what browsers are (rightly) trying to prevent.

I have the following code, and while I do hear the *beep*, I do not get the speech unless the phone is unlocked **and** the browser opened. Is there any way to get speech without these two requirements?

```
function say(data) {
    beep().then(() => {
        window.speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(data));
    });
}

const beeep =
    "data:audio/wav;base64,//uQRAAAAWMSLwUIYAAsYkXgoQ.....AAACU=";
function beep() {
    snd.src = beeep;
    return snd.play();
}
```

Native alternatives do 'speak' when asleep, although I don't know whether they are using a speech synthesiser or just playing sound files.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you should send the events vía push notifications, this notifications can be triggered when the app is in background.
[Here is a basic example](https://blog.sashido.io/android-push-notifications-with-sashido-step-by-step/)

Comment: this seems to be Java. I'm trying to do this in the browser